# make divs stay inside parent div with margins

Tags: css, html

i've been looking around to fix this, i havent seen a good answer on why this happens and how i can fix it..
basically i have a div that i set to 100% width and height, inside i have like a tabs section like on a broswer, i added a margin and padding to the main area, and when i set the tabs div to full width it sticks out some pixels, whats the correct way to deal with child divs sticking out of parents divs when playing with %'s and margins/padding

```
<div class="appview_fullscreen app_ama">
 <center><strong>AMAMAMAMAMAMA</strong> </br>
    <i>AMAMAMA</i>
 </center>
<div class="main_area">
    <div class="tabs_area">

    </div>
    <div class="main_window">

    </div>
    <div class="troubleshoot_area">

    </div>
    <div class="timeline">

    </div>
 </div>
</div>


.appview_fullscreen
{
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.app_ama
{

}
.main_area
{
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.tabs_area
{
    border: 1px solid green;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/S8RC3/

Comment: I'm not sure where you've looked, but if you Google 'child div wider than parent div' then the first result is a big article by CSS tricks about this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By simply removing `100%` from the `DIV` elements.

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ETIwuGAm/1/edit)

```
.main_area{
    /* width:100%; Why? I'm a DIV! */
    border: 1px solid green;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.tabs_area{
    /* width:100%; Why? I'm a DIV! */
    border: 1px solid green;
    height: 20px;
}
```

DIV as being a *Block level* element is already wide as it's parent container.

Additionally you have a typo: `</br>` should be `<br />`, `<br/>` or `<br>`

Comment: I also had to remove `min-width` and `min-height`

Comment: @Prometheus yes, if you need to override previously applied styles only. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

For your padding and border, use `box-sizing: border-box;`.

Comment: border box equals my specific border? 1px solid green?

Comment: @user3059823 no. border-box makes the width and height properties include the padding and border. However, it looks as if [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20342475) might be better. :P

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan what am I supposed to be looking for? Or are those links for @user3059823?

Comment: @ShengSlogar SO, being a community site, and those links are from reliable resources... it's for everybody.

Comment: @RokoC.Bulijan sorry. I thought you were trying to correct an error I made, as you had already posted an answer that *didn't* use box sizing. Plus, people seem to use @ when talking to someone other than the author of a post. :)